# Keras model accuracy score? Is it this a good result?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I trained my algorithm through 3 epoches and got these results:

Is this good accuracy, val_loss, and val_accuracy? It seems too good to be true.

Train on 256326 samples, validate on 28481 samples
Epoch 1/3
256326/256326 [==============================] - 82s 318us/sample - loss: 0.0373 - accuracy: 0.9983 - val_loss: 0.0116 - val_accuracy: 0.9983
Epoch 2/3
256326/256326 [==============================] - 83s 322us/sample - loss: 0.0119 - accuracy: 0.9983 - val_loss: 0.0082 - val_accuracy: 0.9983
Epoch 3/3
256326/256326 [==============================] - 83s 324us/sample - loss: 0.0072 - accuracy: 0.9983 - val_loss: 0.0034 - val_accuracy: 0.9983

Comment: The loss is decreasing over epochs, the accuracy is good. Maybe the task is very easy. I don't see any problem here other, maybe, than your val score being better than your train score, but it can happen.

Comment: Exact same accuracy for both sets looks suspicious. Is your dataset balanced? Also, check for data leaks, validation samples may be same as training or very similar.

Comment: @AlexM4 its not exactly the same accuracy, the loss is decreasing with epoches

Comment: @AlexM4 Please check the data. I think it doesn't have a lot of variations. Redundancy in data is making model overfit very quickly.